# MVP Matrix * Vector3 = Black Screen?

Tags: opengl, matrix, vector, windows

I'm relatively new to computer graphics so please take it easy. I created a **ModelViewProjection** Matrix and I sent it to **my shader**:

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0)in vec3 vert;

uniform mat4 MVP;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = MVP*vec4(vert, 1);
}
```

When I do this I get a black screen, so I guessed I made the MVP matrix wrong but when I pass an identity matrix to MVP I still get a black screen. If I totally remove the MVP matrix from shader and code I get the desired image (a white triangle on black background).

**Should't an identity matrix multiplied with a vector return the vector unchanged ?**
Ex:

```
Vector3 a
    I * a = a
```

**How should I construct a MVP matrix ?**
I do it like this:

```
fovy = 120;
aspect  = width/height;
M = T * R * S;
V = lookat(position, target, up);
P = perspective(fovy, aspect, 0.3f, 1000.0f);
MVP = P * V * M;
```

**What am I doing wrong ?**

**SOLVED**

I had to call `glUseProgram(program)` before `glUniformMatrix4fv()` or any other uniform call.

Comment: What is your triangle coordinates?

Comment: Isn't fovy supposed to be in radians?

Comment: #concept3d vertex1(0.0f, 0.0f, 0)
    vertex2(0.5f, 0, 0)
    vertex3(0, 0.2f, 0)

Comment: #fastinvsqrt Maybe, but why don't it show anything when using identity matrix ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to call `glUseProgram(program)` before `glUniformMatrix4fv()` or any other uniform call.